# Expose com.apple.barcodescanner on home screen or a shortcut?

Tags: ios, mobile-device-management

I am trying to solve the following ask:

Shared iphones within a healthcare setting, ipads are not an option. They need these phones to scan QR codes and open a website that allows the nurses to fill out surveys, but they don't want any website data saved. They also cannot have access to the camera app or photos since its again healthcare and you don't want patient photos ending up on there by mistake. I can solve for almost all of their asks on this using the hidden code scanner app, tested a fully supervised device and it worked great. My issue is just trying to make access easier to the code scanner app outside of being able to add it to the control center, really would like to just have a shortcut or something on the main home screen they can click on to open it. I just cannot land on a way to get this done, maybe its not even possible due to how the app is hidden by apple? workspace one is the mdm btw

Comment: You can’t expose a library/plist to the home screen or the Shortcuts, this sounds more like a dev question and belongs on [SO], but as written, seems rather broad and needs some clarity.

Comment: Rather broadly? If you type code scanner into a iPhone it’s shows an app, I want to add that to the Home Screen, is it possible, yes or no? I tagged it with mobile device management, not sure how much more direct it could be